# Oracle 11gR2: slow insert performance, then fast insert performance

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to figure out root cause of slow Oracle insert performance.  I am running the exact same SQL twice - both times selecting 1000 rows from an Oracle table and inserting back into same table.  First INSERT runs in 76 seconds.  Second INSERT (same command) runs in < 1 second.  Would love to hear any ideas of what may be going on with the former.

> INSERT INTO MY_TABLE SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;

This is not a parse issue, INSERT of 1 row (ROWNUM <=1) was run immediately before first-1000-row-insert and it ran very fast.

Let me know if there's any trace data that would help.

(EDIT: Gah! - explored meta.stackoverflow, found advice for formatting this data from Excel into ASCII-Art, put results in between code tags as recommended... and still got this mangled mess with all newlines removed.... META-HELP please someone let me know how to format this into a readable table that does not remove newlines!)

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║                    StatName                    ║ First Insert ║ Second Insert ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ active txn count during cleanout               ║           17 ║            18 ║
║ buffer is not pinned count                     ║            8 ║             0 ║
║ buffer is pinned count                         ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ bytes received via SQL*Net from client         ║          145 ║           145 ║
║ bytes sent via SQL*Net to client               ║           79 ║            79 ║
║ calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss              ║            4 ║             1 ║
║ calls to kcmgas                                ║            4 ║            16 ║
║ calls to kcmgcs                                ║           49 ║            50 ║
║ cell physical IO interconnect bytes            ║     16080896 ║        147456 ║
║ change write time                              ║            0 ║             1 ║
║ cleanout - number of ktugct calls              ║           17 ║            18 ║
║ consistent gets                                ║           71 ║            68 ║
║ consistent gets - examination                  ║           17 ║            18 ║
║ consistent gets from cache                     ║           71 ║            68 ║
║ consistent gets from cache (fastpath)          ║           50 ║            50 ║
║ CPU used by this session                       ║           17 ║             3 ║
║ CPU used when call started                     ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ cursor authentications                         ║            0 ║             1 ║
║ db block changes                               ║         2131 ║          2124 ║
║ db block gets                                  ║         5166 ║          5160 ║
║ db block gets from cache                       ║         5166 ║          5160 ║
║ db block gets from cache (fastpath)            ║         1035 ║          1037 ║
║ DB time                                        ║         7787 ║           104 ║
║ deferred (CURRENT) block cleanout applications ║            2 ║             0 ║
║ enqueue releases                               ║           22 ║             0 ║
║ enqueue requests                               ║           25 ║             0 ║
║ execute count                                  ║            3 ║             1 ║
║ file io wait time                              ║     76571222 ║       1010237 ║
║ free buffer inspected                          ║         3026 ║            64 ║
║ free buffer requested                          ║         1979 ║            34 ║
║ Heap Segment Array Inserts                     ║           35 ║            35 ║
║ hot buffers moved to head of LRU               ║          631 ║             2 ║
║ HSC Heap Segment Block Changes                 ║           35 ║            35 ║
║ IMU Flushes                                    ║            1 ║             0 ║
║ index scans kdiixs1                            ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ logical read bytes from cache                  ║     42901504 ║      42827776 ║
║ logons cumulative                              ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ logons current                                 ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ no work - consistent read gets                 ║           22 ║            18 ║
║ non-idle wait count                            ║         1732 ║            19 ║
║ non-idle wait time                             ║         7776 ║           101 ║
║ opened cursors cumulative                      ║            3 ║             1 ║
║ opened cursors current                         ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ parse count (hard)                             ║            1 ║             0 ║
║ parse count (total)                            ║            2 ║             1 ║
║ physical read bytes                            ║     16080896 ║        147456 ║
║ physical read IO requests                      ║         1836 ║            18 ║
║ physical read total bytes                      ║     16080896 ║        147456 ║
║ physical read total IO requests                ║         1836 ║            18 ║
║ physical read total multi block requests       ║            1 ║             0 ║
║ physical reads                                 ║         1963 ║            18 ║
║ physical reads cache                           ║         1963 ║            18 ║
║ physical reads cache prefetch                  ║          253 ║             0 ║
║ prefetch clients - default                     ║            1 ║             1 ║
║ process last non-idle time                     ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ recursive calls                                ║           15 ║             0 ║
║ recursive cpu usage                            ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ redo entries                                   ║         1079 ║          1073 ║
║ redo ordering marks                            ║            4 ║            16 ║
║ redo size                                      ║       463216 ║        453624 ║
║ redo subscn max counts                         ║           18 ║            16 ║
║ Requests to/from client                        ║            1 ║             1 ║
║ session connect time                           ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ session cursor cache count                     ║            2 ║             0 ║
║ session cursor cache hits                      ║            1 ║             0 ║
║ session logical reads                          ║         5237 ║          5228 ║
║ session pga memory                             ║       393216 ║             0 ║
║ session pga memory max                         ║       393216 ║             0 ║
║ session uga memory                             ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ session uga memory max                         ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ shared hash latch upgrades - no wait           ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ sorts (memory)                                 ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ sorts (rows)                                   ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client              ║            1 ║             1 ║
║ table fetch by rowid                           ║            4 ║             0 ║
║ table scan blocks gotten                       ║           18 ║            18 ║
║ table scan rows gotten                         ║         1017 ║          1017 ║
║ table scans (long tables)                      ║            1 ║             1 ║
║ table scans (short tables)                     ║            0 ║             0 ║
║ undo change vector size                        ║       127384 ║        126740 ║
║ user calls                                     ║            2 ║             2 ║
║ user I/O wait time                             ║         7776 ║           101 ║
║ workarea executions - optimal                  ║            0 ║             0 ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝`
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the INSERT which is taking time and not the SELECT in the first run? Did you try running just the SELECT part and see what's hapening

Comment: Yes- definitely the INSERT.  Was able to reproduce effect with 2 step: 1) push 1k rows to side table 2) push rows from side-table to main table... confirmed that #1 is very fast, #2 is very, very slow...  following up on Justin's answer below next, may have some more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two appears to be primarily due to a difference in physical reads.  That implies that when you ran the first `INSERT` statement, the blocks you needed to `SELECT` were not in cache and had to be read from disk.  When you ran the statement again, the blocks you needed were still in cache so you only had to read them from RAM.  Reading from RAM is, obviously, much faster than reading from disk.

That being said, it's hard to imagine that it should really take 76 seconds to read 1000 rows of data (a total of ~16 MB) from disk (`file io wait time` went from just north of 76 seconds to just north of 1 second and `physical read bytes` goes from 16 MB to 150 kb).  That's a rather insanely slow I/O speed that implies that there is some sort of issue in the underlying disk subsystem.

Comment: To be more precise,We name the cache here as _Exadata_ `Cells`. Statistics starting with `cell%` are Exadata's

Comment: This is interesting - the cell% values jumped out at me as well - this is not an Exadata database, and I have no idea why these interconnect stats would even be showing up.  If it helps, this is an "all of a sudden" development... no major changes to database, but one day, bulk loads that used to take 2 hours were running for 2 days.  Only blessing is, it's dev box... but, really need to get to bottom of it before it appears in prod.  For I/O, i have done some basic read/write "dd" tests on disk device - no red flags there, but if theres a more formal test recommended, I'm all ears.

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick - Are you dealing with local disks?  Or with a SAN?  If you look at an AWR report, are you seeing outsized average read times for some files or some tablespaces?

Comment: Issue was with underlying disk array.  I made the unfortunate mistake of benchmarking that using "dd" utility but only running a 100MB test.  Mea Culpa.  Caching of the array handled that load easily, so I got the impression - "disk is fine".  3 days later... "Hmmm, maybe I should try 8GB test".  Sure enough, first 100MB = 250MB/ps.  Remaining 7.9GB = 15 MB/sec.  Lesson learned :-) Here is the command that confirmed the disk issue.  Shell1: "# iostat -xtcni 5 120 > /tmp/iostats.txt"  Shell2 (after cd to database directory): "# time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=8k count=1000000 && sync"

Comment: One side apology - sorry to drag this out - since issue was on dev box, had to work to find bandwidth to deal with it directly.